# Accessing a PHP stdClass Object in Javascript/Smarty

Tags: php, javascript, smarty, stdclass

I have a stclass object which i am initializing in PHP code. 
The object returns

```
object(stdClass)[238]
  public '0' => string 'Jun 20, 2012 03:02 PM' (length=21)
  public '1' => string 'Jun 20, 2012 03:26 PM' (length=21)
  public '2' => string 'Jun 21, 2012 01:12 PM' (length=21)
```

on doing var_dum($myObjectName)

I am passing this to smarty template where i need to access values of stdClass object at index [i] based on a javascript variable .

I have tried several of these:

```
{/literal} {$myObjectName}{literal} 
{/literal} {$myObjectName.0}{literal} 
{/literal} {$myObjectName.'0'}{literal} 
{/literal} {$myObjectName.'myLocalJSVariable'}{literal}
```

but i am not bale to fetch value of Object at particular index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest you use [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) to dump your data to json, save that to something accessible to javascript, and then access your data from javascript?

`{$myObjectName->javaScriptVariable}` sounds just like you were trying to access some client data on the server, or some server data on the client - which is not possible unless you *provide* the data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `{$myObjectName->0}`?

If you want to use it the way you use arrays, you must pass an *array version* of the object to Smarty:

```
$smarty->assign('myObjectName', get_object_vars($obj));
```

The [**`get_object_vars()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) method returns a named array of all properties from an object.

Comment: Which solution? The first, using the object itself, or the second, passing it as array?

Comment: the first one... i need to use the myObjectName->3 value in the template file. the number 3 is a javascript variable which i will assign to the code so as my code to access an object's member becomes like : {$myObjectName->javaScriptVariable}

Comment: What the output of `var_dump($yourObject)` from PHP?

Comment: object(stdClass)[238]
  public '0' => string 'Jun 20, 2012 03:02 PM' (length=21)
  public '1' => string 'Jun 20, 2012 03:26 PM' (length=21)
  public '2' => string 'Jun 21, 2012 01:12 PM' (length=21)
  public '3' => string 'Jun 21, 2012 01:25 PM' (length=21)

Comment: Ok, are you using Smarty2 or Smarty3?

Comment: I just wanted to try it by myself to help you, but I can't create an object like this. In PHP, variable and properties names cannot start with a number.

Comment: let me give you some more code.. that may help you what i am doing


    foreach ($variables as $var) {
               $myClassObject->$$var = $this->functionName($var1, $var2);
            }
   
   now here, $variables is an array with var_dump as 
   
   array
      0 => int 0
      1 => int 1
      2 => int 2
      3 => int 3
 </pre></code>

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass to smarty a reference to your object?

```
$smarty->assign('myObjectName', &$obj);
```

Then in smarty you can use the {$myObjectName->whatever} syntax...

Comment: Unless you're running PHP4 you don't *need* to pass objects by reference.